# Getting different visualization results for jupiter and datacamp existing code shell. How to solve this?

Tags: visualization, matplotlib, histogram

**The left one image is in jupiter notebook and the right one is from datacamp exercises. Can anyone please let me know why I am getting different results in Jupiter? Used hacker statistics to calculate the chances of winning a bet. Used random number generators, loops, and Matplotlib to gain a competitive edge!**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(123)
# Simulate random walk 500 times
all_walks = []
for i in range(500) :
   random_walk = [0]
   for x in range(100) :
       step = random_walk[-1]
       dice = np.random.randint(1,7)
       if dice <= 2:
        step = max(0, step - 1)
       elif dice <= 5:
        step = step + 1
       else:
        step = step + np.random.randint(1,7)
       if np.random.rand() <= 0.001 :
        step = 0
       random_walk.append(step)
  all_walks.append(random_walk)
```

## Create and plot np_aw_t

np_aw_t = np.transpose(np.array(all_walks))

## Select last row from np_aw_t: ends

ends = np_aw_t[-1, :]

## Plot histogram of ends, display plot

plt.hist(ends)
plt.show()`
[image]